# Cross Join Created by Hibernate for Table/Column Referenced Twice

Tags: hibernate

Suppose we have 2 separate child objects of the same type referenced in a Hibernate domain object.

```
//uni-directional one-to-one association to Person
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="ACKNOWLEDGE_BY", referencedColumnName="UNIQUEIDENTIFIER")
private Person acknowledgeBy;

//uni-directional one-to-one association to Person
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="UNIQUEIDENTIFIER", referencedColumnName="UNIQUEIDENTIFIER")
private Person employee;
```

This structure always produces a `CROSS JOIN` to the `Person` table which is incorrect. Our goal is to get rid of the `CROSS JOIN` and have these be separate Outer Joins.

Why is a `CROSS JOIN` produced?

Answer (score 0):

Hardly could understand what you want...

Could you try this answer?

```java
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "ACKNOWLEDGE_BY", unique = true)
private Person acknowledgeBy;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="UNIQUEIDENTIFIER", unique = true)
private Person employee;
//...
```